why multi-HTMLCanvasElement.captureStream() cause my gpu memory Inflated？
Bt(this, Se, Ft(this, Ee).captureStream(0)),
    Bt(this, Re, Ft(this, Ee)),
    e.appendChild(Ft(this, Re));
    const a = document.createElement("video");
    a.style.width = "100%",
    a.style.height = "100%",
    a.width = Ft(this, Ee).width,
    a.height = Ft(this, Ee).height,
    a.srcObject = Ft(this, Se),
    a.addEventListener("resize", ( () => {
        a.width = Ft(this, Ee).width,
        a.height = Ft(this, Ee).height
    }
    ));
    const s = setInterval(( () => {
        a.play().then(( () => {
            var t, n;
            Bt(this, Re, a),
            e.removeChild(Ft(this, Ee)),
            e.appendChild(Ft(this, Re)),
            null == (t = Ft(this, Me).shift()) || t(),
            null == (n = Ft(this, Me).shift()) || n(),
            Ft(this, Me).push(Lt(this, Ue, We).call(this)),
            Ft(this, Me).push(Ft(this, Ve).call(this)),
            clearInterval(s)
        }
        )).catch(( () => {}
        ))
    }
    ), 1e3)

The gpu memory will be full until I open 5-8 tabs which use codes above.

They both use canvas to capture stream.
It's even more strange that I don't open the camera.
How can I solve this problem?

